# does there exist an entire function with this property?

Tags: complex-analysis

We need to show that there is no polynomial $P$ with complex coefficients such that $P(n)=(-1)^n\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Does there exist an entire function with this property? Hints only, please.

Comment: polynomial cannot take any value infinitely many times, unless it is a constant function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a polynomial $P(z)$ satisfies your condition, then $P+1$ has infinitely many zeroes (the odd integers) so $P+1=0$, hence $P=-1$. But then it cannot satisfy the condition on the even integers. Contradiction.

For the existence of an entire function satisfying your condition, let's look at $\cos (\pi z)$.
This is an entire function.
We have $\cos (\pi 2n)= 1$ and $\cos(\pi (2n+1))=-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ . So it works.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Regarding the polynomial. Assume that there is a polynomial $P(z) \in \mathbb{C}[z]$ such that $P(n)=(-1)^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Clearly $P$ is not constant: $P(1)=-1$ while $P(2)=1$. Consider the polynomial restricted to the even integers. We see that $P(2k) = 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If such a polynomial were to exist then you would need a non-constant polynomial to take a given value infinitely many times. Is that possible?

Think about the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra). Any non-constant degree-$n$ polynomial has exactly, when counted with multiplicities, exactly $n$-roots.

Comment: Maybe a nitpick: The main point of FT of Algebra is *existence* of a root of a nonconstant polynomial in $\mathbb C$, whereas here we need only finiteness of the set of the roots, which is not particular to $\mathbb C$ and would hold over any other field (or integral domain).  It is enough to consider the [factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem).

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the FToA is also stated as follows: "*Every non-zero, single-variable, degree $n$ polynomial with complex coefficients has, counted with multiplicity, exactly $n$ roots.*" The equivalence of the two statements can be proven through the use of successive polynomial division. Using the FToA (or indeed a lemma) is perfectly valid and there are no nits to be picked. Perhaps a simpler proof exists, but I didn't say one didn't.

Comment: Yes it is possible. The polynomial constant equal to this value. You need to use the value at odd integers to get a contradiction.

Comment: @julien I'm sorry, I don't follow. It is made explicit that $P(n) = (-1)^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and so $P$ *cannot possibly* be constant because $P(1) \neq P(2)$.

Comment: @FlybyNight Your argument says that $P(2k)=1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. From here, you can only deduce that $P$ is constant equal to $1$. Then you need to look at any odd integer, say $P(1)=-1$, to get a contradiction. Your last question seems to imply that a polynomial can not take a given value infinitely many times. This is not true. The constant polynomial equal to this value does.

Comment: @julien The OP tells us that $P(n) = (-1)^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, which means that $P$ is non-constant. Restricting this definition to the even integers: $P(2k)=1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ means that we have a non-constant polynomial that takes the value $1$ infinitely many times. This gives a contradiction. Of course a constant polynomial takes a value infinitely many times, but the OP's definition tells us that the polynomial *cannot possibly be constant*!

Comment: @FlyByNight Yes. "Maybe you meant your question to be: You would need a non-constant polynomial to take a given value infinitely many times. Is this possible?" Otherwise, sorry to repeat myself, a polynomial can very well take a given value infinitely many times.

Comment: @julien I mentioned the non-constant condition in my original post. It is clear that $P$ is non-constant.

Answer (score 3):

If there were such a polynomial $P$, then $Q(z):=P(z)-1$ is a non-constant polynomial with infinitely-many zeros. (Why?) Can this happen?

As for finding an entire function with the desired property, try basic transformations of a familiar periodic function.

Comment: Yeah, should be easy as pie.